# Configure Bootstrap for 6 cells to auto fit full screen with responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootply

I am trying to get a grid that allows me to have a  center carousel with corners for icons etc.

The code I have is using Bootstrap 3 @ http://www.bootply.com/Mbi11Tfvq5#

I can't get the center cell to respond and pull in to allow the bottom row to show up. The image creates a scroll bar.

What I am doing wrong ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">ax</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 f">b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">ay</div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">am</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 f">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/3200x3200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">an</div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">ah</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 f">b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 f">ai</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

css

```
    /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.f {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000 ;
  }

.y {
  background: yellow ;
  }

.x {
    hight: auto;
  }
```

I am hoping to create the following structure in the page: 
[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not too concern about supporting legacy browsers, you can use CSS3 `Flexible Box` layout for the second row. The defining aspect of the flex layout is the ability to alter its items' width and/or height to best fill the available space on any display device. A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow.

Your second row would look something like this:

```
  <div class="row flex">
      <div class="col-sm-1 blue">am</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/3200x3200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 blue">an</div>
  </div>
```

Then set the `display` value for `.flex` to something like:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

This will get you something similar to your illustration. Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/xbjca5z1/

Comment: But the jsfiddle does not make the image smaller when I resize the browser. the goal was to have the center cell image be responsive

Comment: Works in the fiddle for me.

Comment: *the goal was to have the center cell image be responsive*. The `img-responsive` class should have done that for you.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the suggestion. the responsive tage enables the image only when the broswer is set at certain size and not at all other time - I assume that is a function of the image size. either way.